# Process never exits after successfully receiving from MPSC channel

Tags: rust

Here's the code:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {

    //spawn threads 
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    for mut i in 0 .. 10 {
        let txc = tx.clone();   //clone from the main sender
        thread::spawn( move || {            
            i += 20;
            println!("Sending: {}", i);
            txc.send(i).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                eprintln!("{}", e);
            });
        });
    }

    for received in rx {
        println!("Received: {}", received);
    }

}
```

The code runs successfully but it hangs and the process never exits at the end.

I thought it could be related to closing the channel ends and I tried dropping by `tx.drop()` and `rx.drop()` but the compiler gave an error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

`tx` in your main thread is not dropped until the end of the `main` function, and `rx` will not be closed until all senders have been dropped.

To fix this, you can manually drop it with `drop(tx)` after you have started all of your threads:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {

    //spawn threads 
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    for mut i in 0 .. 10 {
        let txc = tx.clone();   //clone from the main sender
        thread::spawn( move || {            
            i += 20;
            println!("Sending: {}", i);
            txc.send(i).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                eprintln!("{}", e);
            });
        });
    }

    // drop tx manually, to ensure that only senders in spawned threads are still in use
    drop(tx);

    for received in rx {
        println!("Received: {}", received);
    }

}
```